# Ajax Save to server on wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to save a PDF to server on Wordpress, When I press submit on the form and look at Console I get the messages:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

and

> jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 POST https://eazyfreight.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400

My Code:

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_so56917978_upload', 'so56917978_upload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_so56917978_upload', 'so56917978_upload' );
function so56917978_upload() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
        file_put_contents( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/POD/pod.pdf' , $data );
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "No Data Sent";
    }

    die();
}
```

JS

```
function sendToServer() { 
            html2canvas(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas){
                    console.log("#pdfsubmit clicked");

                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4' );
                    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);

                    var pdf = doc.output('blob');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: jspod.ajax_url,
                        type: 'post',
                        async: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data:{
                            data: pdf,
                            action:'so56917978_upload',
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Any help sorting the error and then sending the document to the server would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but it seems like your code is fine, i would have done it the same way.

Try updating your jQuery version since you are using a veeery old version..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the jQuery version (although it should be included automatically by Wordrpress but for some reason is not on this page). I am now getting `No Data Sent` which implies that I am not sending the generated PDF correctly. Is there anything you can see that might cause that?

Comment: after refreshing, I ma now getting the error `POST https://website.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400`

Comment: Put a var_dump("Test") right after the function opening of so56917978_upload to test if this works now. You should see the output in Chrome dev tools under network - >admin-ajax

Comment: Nothing because its not even making it to the PHP code. In wordpress it needs to go through admin-ajax.php and then route to functions.php where my so56917978_upload function is but there appears to be an issue with routing it there

Comment: Your code looks fine in my opionion. Try console.log(jspod.ajax_url); inside ur js. Or even try just putting "admin-ajax.php" hardcoded

Comment: Ive done the hard coding. but I am assuming that  because it gives the error - `POST https://website.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400` that it knows I want to access admin-ajax.php. but there is something stopping it. I have no idea what might be preventing it from going through

Comment: This is weird.. my last idea would be removing the "async: false,". If this doesnt help i cant help you anymore :(

Comment: Tried that as well. no difference. Its puzzling the life out of me, i have no idea